# Returning another NSView subclass in 'initWithCoder' results in error "This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder""

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsvisualeffectview

I want to make a backwards-compatible background view for my application (OS X 10.6+) and then use it inside my **Application.xib**.

I made a subclass of NSView which returns NSVisualEffectView or NSView (depends on macOS version).

BackgroundView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface BackgroundView : NSView

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

BackgroundView.m

```
#import "BackgroundView.h"

@implementation BackgroundView

- (instancetype)init {
    if (@available(macOS 10.10, *)) {
        NSVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[NSVisualEffectView alloc] init];
        [self applyPropertiesForVisualEffectView: visualEffectView];
    }
    
    return [super init];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (@available(macOS 10.10, *)) {
        NSVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[NSVisualEffectView alloc] initWithCoder:coder];
        [self applyPropertiesForVisualEffectView: visualEffectView];
        
        // !!!"This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:"!!!
        return (BackgroundView *)visualEffectView;
    }
    
    return [super initWithCoder:coder];
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    if (@available(macOS 10.10, *)) {
        NSVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[NSVisualEffectView alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
        [self applyPropertiesForVisualEffectView: visualEffectView];
        
        return (BackgroundView *)visualEffectView;
    }
    
    return [super initWithFrame: frameRect];
}

- (void)applyPropertiesForVisualEffectView: (NSVisualEffectView *)visualEffectView API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.10)){
    [visualEffectView setState:NSVisualEffectStateActive];
    [visualEffectView setBlendingMode:NSVisualEffectBlendingModeBehindWindow];
}

@end
```

Then I inserted my **BackgroundView** class name as the class for the windows' main view.
[image: My XIB main view Custom Class]

And then ticked off "**Prefers coder at runtime**":
[image: Ticked off option "Prefers coder at runtime"]

But I'm getting this error for whatever reason.
[image: This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:]

How can I fix this issue?
I don't want to use some dynamic class injections like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914918/how-to-use-nsvisualeffectview-backwards-compatible-with-osx-10-10) because it looks like an awful solution in 2023.
I know I can add NSVisualEffect as a subview but I don't think it's as a good practice.

Thanks.